# How to vectorize greedy algorithm in R?

Tags: r, algorithm, vectorization, greedy

I'm writing an R script that implements a greedy algorithm to optimize a function. As a simple example, suppose I have a vector of positive numbers to be distributed among 3 clusters. I want to minimize the total within-cluster distance in each cluster. I use the greedy algorithm of distributing the numbers one at a time and placing each number in the cluster that has the smallest sum of distances between that number and the numbers already in the cluster. Here's an R script to implement that algorithm:

```
n <- 100
set.seed(0)
x <- rnorm(n)
cluster <- integer(n)

total_distance <- function(c, x, cluster){
  if(!any(cluster == c)){
    total_dist <- 0
  } else{
    total_dist <- sum(abs(x[cluster == c] - x[which.min(cluster > 0)]))
  }
  return(total_dist)
}

for(i in 1:n){
  within_cluster_distances <- mapply(total_distance, 1:3,
                                     MoreArgs = list(x = x, cluster = cluster))
  cluster[i] <- which.min(within_cluster_distances)
}

> cluster
  [1] 1 2 3 1 2 3 2 2 2 1 1 3 3 2 2 2 2 3 1 3 2 1 2 1 2 1 1 3 3 2 2 3 2 3 1 1 1 2 1 2 1 1 2 3 3 3 3 1 1 2 2 2 1 3 2 2 1 2 3 3 2 2 3 2 3 2 3
 [68] 1 2 2 2 2 3 2 1 1 2 2 3 3 3 1 1 2 2 2 1 2 1 1 1 3 2 3 1 2 2 1 2 1
```

Is it possible (or even desirable) to vectorize the loop to obtain the `cluster` vector? I don't know how to vectorize when the values in the output vector depend on other values in that vector.

EDIT: I realize that the greedy algorithm outlined above is not an effective clustering method. The problem described above is not the problem that I am actually trying to solve. My question is about whether it is possible and beneficial to vectorize the loop in my code example.

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to use `stats::kmeans`:

```
kmeans(x, 3)$cluster
```

Check which is more closely packed:

```
cldist <- function(v) sum(abs(outer(v, v, `-`)))

tapply(x, cluster, FUN=cldist)
#       1        2        3 
#1086.007 1132.614 1019.575 

tapply(x, kmeans(x, 3)$cluster, FUN=cldist)
#       1        2        3 
#234.8734 722.5750 374.7199
```

Comment: Thank you, but the example I gave above is not actually the problem I'm trying to solve, and `stats::kmeans` will not help me solve my real problem. My question is about whether it is possible and beneficial to vectorize the loop in my code example.